# Can't install pygame on pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm, python-3.8

I've successfully installed pygame on my computer. When I type "import pygame" there is no error so that means that pygame is installed on my laptop. But, when I type the same thing on Pycharm, I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

I have initialized pygame, so that's not the problem. I've also tried to install pygame from pycharm and I get this error every time I try to install it:

[image: EOFError]

I've tried everything. The interpreter is correct, too. How can I proceed?

Comment: The EOFError suggests that the last file mentioned in the traceback isn't complete. Maybe try adding the `--no-cache-dir` option to the pip install to re-download pygame?

Comment: thank you for your tip. Unfortunately, that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're using two different python interpreters on your pycharm and on your terminal.

Please,

- check the python version on the terminal by `python3 --version`
- And then go to pycharm -> file -> settings -> project -> project
  interpreter

and check if both python are the same.

Comment: I appreciate your tip. But, I checked, and basically I have the Python 3.8.2 version. On pycharm I can only use Python 3.8. I am suggesting that both Python versions are the same, so that's not the problem.

Comment: @AmateurDeveloper having the same version of python doesn't mean that the interpreter is the same. Try manually adding path to the python for which pygame module is installed correctly in the pycharm settings.

Comment: @Mirac7 Couldn't understand your comment, and as for the guy who asked the question- if you'd make sure that the python on terminal and pycharm are the same only then we could continue into investigating more the problem, cause if the versions are the same then maybe it's a pycharm issue altough from my experience it wont be, and if the versions are not the same will just use pip for the 3.8 python on pycharm to install pygame.

Comment: what exactly do you mean "are the same" ?

Comment: Pointing to the same path, the exact same python program.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sudo easy_install-3.8 pygame
```

(This will install the dependencies.)

```sh
sudo pip3 install pygame
```

Comment: Just want to mention, the error output hints a Windows installation. Why do you think `sudo` would help?